# Is it a good practice to call Struts action through constructor in another action?

Tags: struts2

I have two Struts2 actions. I want to use a public method of a action in another action. Is it Ok that I can call an action through `new` operator and call its public method? (For the sake of reusing some common functionality)

```
public class OneAction extends ActionSupport{
public void doSomeThing(){
    // some code
}

public String execute(){
    // some code
}
}

 public class AnotherAction extends ActionSupport{

public String execute(){
    /* is it ok?*/
    new OneAction().doSomeThing();
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(shudder) I would not.  I'd refactor the common functionality into a separate class that both can call.  But that class would be a POJO, not an Action.

I'd be careful about embedding functionality in Actions.  I think they're firmly in the web tier camp.  You should do little more than validate and bind parameters into objects, hand them off to POJOs for processing, and package results for return.

Comment: Hmm. Right, I should better shift that common functionality to service layer. And to invoke service layer in both actions.

Comment: A service layer - exactly.  POJO interfaces and implementations.  These will be usable even if you decide to ditch Struts someday, or call them from a mobile platform.

Comment: But should I have request object in that POJO? So that my logic of session/cookies can be mentioned there too.

Comment: No, validate and map the request object into the POJO.  No web objects should be used in the service layer.  Otherwise it's impossible to disconnect the two.

Comment: @TahirAkram What duffymo said +1. Service layers should accept *only* framework-neutral parameters. This allows trivial, isolated testing, and fosters easier re-use. This is pretty easy with S2, because you almost *never* need to see Servlet Spec artifacts in actions (and when you do, you probably would prefer an interceptor to massage required data out of them).

Comment: You can use Spring with Struts.  I'd recommend it.

Answer (score 2):

I plus-oned @duffymo's answer, but here's some more food for thought.

If the functionality is common across actions, it belongs in either a base action (if web-related), or a utility class (either web-related or not). Which makes the most sense depends a lot on context.

Along those contextual lines, depending on the actual functionality you're talking about, it might make more sense yet somewhere else--in an interceptor, an aspect, a mixin (how to do that depends on the implementation language), etc. Without knowing details, it's difficult to be more specific.

Comment: I have scenerio, when user login and it's time to change his password. I will redirect to another action. User will change it's password. And same logic will run that is written in LoginAction for user success login. So I have to put this login success logic some where in common. To be used in these both actions.

Comment: No, both Actions should call an AuthenticationService that has methods to validate and authenticate the user.  Let the changePassword method in the AuthenticationService call its login method.  Do it all  in the service; don't redirect between Actions.